# Is there a python function I can use to group retail banking transactions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Is there perhaps another function in Python I can use to group customers' transactions? Let's say a specific word is contained in a transaction, and there are multiple transactions that have the same name, then group them together.

I used this code, but it will be too long, because I have thousands of unique transactions from different merchants.

```
temp=tranx.TRANX.fillna("0")
tranx['Activity_2'] = pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("PNP "),"PICKNPAY",
               pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("CHECKERS"), "CHECKERS",
               pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("MRPRICE"), "MRPRICE",
               pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("FOOD LOVER"), "FOODLOVERMARKET",
               pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("DISCHEM"), "DISCHEM",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("DIS-CHEM"), "DISCHEM",           
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("OK FOODS"), "OKFOODS",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("DISCHEM"), "DISCHEM",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("FASHION EXPRESS"), "FASHIONEXPRESS",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("MTC"), "MTC",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("TELECOM"), "TELECOM",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("KFC"), "KFC",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("ACKERMANS"), "ACKERMANS",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("SHOPRITE"), "SHOPRITE",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("USAVE"), "SHOPRITE",            
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("S/STATION"), "SERVICESTATION",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("SERVICE STATION"), "SERVICESTATION",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("SOULSTICE DAY SPA"), "SOULSTICESPA",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("CLICKS" ), "CLICKS",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("JET "), "JET",
                pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("PEP "), "PEP",           
               pd.np.where(temp.str.contains("WOERMANN"), "WOERMANN", "OTHER"))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Is there no way where I can create a list that contains all the merchants and then come up with a loop which loops in every row to identify if the merchant name appears in that row, then IF YES OUTPUT MERCHANT NAME, IF NO CLASSIFY THE TRANSACTION AS OTHER?

Below is a sample of the data:

[image: Transactions Sample]

Comment: What qualifies as a merchant name? Do you already have a list of the merchants? 
What's your typical input and the expected behavior of the function you want?

Comment: No i dont have a merchant list, thats why i need to create my own list

Comment: This is `numpy.select`.  Don't chain `np.where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
list_names = ['PNP','CHECKERS'..]
mapping = ['PICKNPAY', 'CHECKERS' ..]
for i,item in enumerate(list_names):
    trax.loc[trax['Activity_2'].str.contains(item), 'Activity_2'] = mapping[i] 

#replaces inplace
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create a list that contains the name and use for loop to loop into each of them.

```
lst = ['PNP', 'JET'...]
for i in lst:
if df['Name'].str.contains[i]:     #same as your temp
    df['Short_Name'] = i
```

If you have different name you want to give to each row, you can create a another list contains 'Short_Name'('PNP') and other names('PICKNPAY'), and merger the two dataframe.